# Play Cache unable to deserialize case class

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, ehcache

Seems the Play Cache (i.e. ehcache) is having trouble deserializing my case class. I'm seeing  `java.io.InvalidClassException` (no valid constructor)

Is there a straightforward way around this? I really don't want to go down the route of modifying my case classes as per [Efficiently serializing case classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749316/efficiently-serializing-case-classes)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304620/akka-remote-actors-superclass-without-default-constructor. Looks like there are some intricacies around which case class can and which cannot be serialized.